# c# regex expression replacing html escape characters with properly formed html

Tags: c#, html, xml, regex

I have xml data which has been created in such a way that it uses characters like • for bullets.

I am trying to use regular expressions and string.replace to create an html list with no luck

```
        String jobDesc = featuredjob.Description.ToString();
        jobDesc = jobDesc.Replace("&#149;", "<li>");
        jobDesc = jobDesc.Replace("<li>", "</li><li>");

        Regex exp = new Regex( @"(</li><li\>)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        jobDesc = exp.Replace(jobDesc,"<ul><li>");
```

I was tring to do a step by step replacement and got up to the point of trying to replace the first

with the start tags of the list.

Are there any existing libraries/easy ways for doing this as I know there are libraries for doing the opposite conversion?

Comment: This kinda stuff is what xslt was designed for any reason thats not a better choice.

Comment: I am not responsible for the data which contains the html comments.I store the XML data feed in SQL server first to make it queryable. As far as I know xslt wont format html codes like this inside one field of data?

Answer (score 0):

Could you process the data a line at a time:

```
foreach (String eachLine in jobDesc.Split('\n')) {
    eachLine = Regex.Replace(eachLine, @"&#149;(.*)", "<li>$1</li>");
}
```

then wrap the whole string in a ul:

```
jobDesc = String.Format("<ul>{0}</ul>",jobDesc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String jobDesc = @"flip burger
&#149; fun
&#149; fashionable
You will love it
&#149; 401k
&#149; great times
apply today
tell your friends
";

string [] lines = jobDesc.Split(new [] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string bul = "&#149;";
string result = string.Empty;
bool inList = false;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if(line.Contains(bul))
    {
        if(!inList)
        {
            result += "<ul>\n";
            inList = true;
        }
        result += " <li>" + line.Replace(bul, string.Empty).Trim() + "</li>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if(inList)
        {
            result += "</ul>\n";
            inList = false;
        }
        result += line;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
flip burger
<ul>
 <li>fun</li>
 <li>fashionable</li>
</ul>
You will love it
<ul>
 <li>401k</li>
 <li>great times</li>
</ul>
apply today
tell your friends
```